# animating (text) color in jquery with jquery ui

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<!-- include Google's AJAX API loader -->
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<!-- load JQuery and UI from Google (need to use UI to animate colors) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.17/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#menuknop1").hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({"color":"black"}, "slow");
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({"color":"white"}, "slow");
});

});
</script>

<div id="menuknop1"><i>Home</i></div>
```

I'm trying to animate this piece of code so that the text turns black when hovered and white when left the area. Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load jQuery first -- jQuery-UI is a plugin, and doesn't contain jQuery itself:

```
<!-- load JQuery and UI from Google (need to use UI to animate colors) -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Aside from that, your code works just fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/pMeJc/ -- provided you use jQuery 1.7.2.

jsFiddle won't let me select jQuery UI 1.8.18 with jQuery 1.8.0, [so apparently it's not compatible with that version](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Upgrade_Guide). According to the jQuery-UI website, " [1.8.23 fixes all known issues with jQuery 1.8.0](http://blog.jqueryui.com/2012/08/jquery-ui-1-8-23/)."

Comment: I forgot/intentionally didn't paste that into this box assuming people would understand I already have these. Sorry for that, but I already have both of these. Any other form of jquery works.

Comment: +1, Seems there's an error when using jQ 1.8 and UI - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/VzJzn/3/)...

Comment: Adeneo, you are right, it doesn't work with jquery 1.8.0. I've changed it to 1.7.2 now and it's working. So much hassle over this (lol). Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Updated -- you need jQuery-UI 1.8.23 (or later) with jQuery 1.8.0